# How to include Publish profile and application parameters in a package of service fabric application for deployment?

Tags: package, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to package Service fabric application, when i do that i have application manifest and service manifest files but i want to include application parameters and Publish profiles as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what CI system you're using but typically there's three parts to make it all work

1. **Package your application output** + manifests. This is basically the package location output you get from doing an `MSBuild` on your `sfproj`. In below, I'm assuming CI build artifact output go to '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

```
/t:Package /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\applicationpackage
```

2. Include a step in your CI build output to **copy the the parameter and profile files to another folder** - e.g. `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\projectartifacts`

```
**\PublishProfiles\*.xml
**\ApplicationParameters\*.xml
```

3. **Deploy your application**. For this, have a look at the `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` script that's created by Visual Studio when your first created your `.sfproj` *Service Fabric* project. This is also used by Visual Studio when you deploy your application to your local development cluster and you essentially have to perform the same steps to deploy to another cluster.

A simple example assuming your CI artifact output exists in `"$(SF_PackagePath)"`

```
Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 -ApplicationPackagePath "$(SF_PackagePath)\applicationpackage" -PublishProfileFile "$(SF_PackagePath)\projectartifacts\Local.1Node.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This everything i am looking for!

Comment: I tried Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 -ApplicationPackagePath "$(SF_PackagePath)\applicationpackage" -PublishProfileFile "$(SF_PackagePath)\projectartifacts\Local.1Node.xml" command but im getting an error that "The term 'Deploy-FabricApplication' is not recognized as
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"....I should be missing something. Can you please explain it to me?Thankyou! @Adriaan de Beer

Comment: You'll need to install the [SF SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#sdk-installation-only) on the build agent, [AzDo example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/service-fabric-deploy?view=azure-devops#prerequisites)

Comment: is there any way to run DeployServiceFabricApplication.ps1 script without having SF SDK in local machine?  https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144750/adriaan-de-beer

Comment: Have you tried copying  and running this script as part of your build output? This is what I'm doing with my hosted azure builds. They provide a service fabric PowerShell task which doesn't require SDK installation.